# Is the iPhone 6 waterproof or water-resistant?

Tags: iphone, damage, waterproof

Before the iPhone 6 was officially announced by Apple, [several](http://www.cultofmac.com/294449/shatterproof-water-resistant-full-iphone-6-specs/) [reports](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/09/08/china-mobile-iphone-6-specs/) [claimed](http://tabtec.com/apple/meet-new-waterproof-dustproof-iphone-6/) that the device will be waterproof.

However, the announcement and [specifications on Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/specs/) make no mention of it.

It would seem clear that the device is not waterproof, but has this been specifically reported or verified after the announcement?

Comment: The technical specs for that device are not released yet. If Apple had done the work to waterproof the iPhone 6, it would be very odd not to mention that at the sales announcement...

Comment: Unlikely that the iPhone 6 will be any more waterproof than the previous devices, otherwise as bmike suggested, it would've been prominently announced at the event on Sep 9th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 6 is neither waterproof nor water-resistant as marketed by Apple. Though tech journalists have found that the iPhone 6S is semi-water resistant, Only the iPhone 7 is currently certified as being water-resistant.

Comment: This is very much correct. The first models of iPhone to be water proof / water resistant are the 7 and 7+. All models of iPhone will with stand a bit of rain on them while you are walking outside but if any pre 7 model is submerged they will most likely fail