# Does the iPhone 8 have any sort of water resistance or waterproof manufacturing?

Tags: iphone, damage, waterproof

I recently got the iPhone 8. After some research, I found that it had the IP67 rating. I'm not sure what this means though especially for a steamy room.

Does this rating mean that it is fully waterproof, or is it only waterproof for a certain number of meters?

Comment: Ooops... I read this before taking my iPhone to the pool and have it filmed my butterfly stroke for 2 minutes under 3 feet... and nothing happened to it. I was so happy... til now that I realized that I might had broke it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPhone 8 and 8 Plus is **not** waterproof — no smartphone is and [in a break with past iPhones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144747/), Apple now designs for an IP67 rating for dust and water-resistance. You can read more about how IP ratings work [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code).

In a nutshell, as far as water is concerned, an IP rating of 67 means your iPhone 8 can be fully submerged in up to 1 meter of water for up to 30 minutes without being damaged.

So, will an iPhone 8 die if it takes a brief dip in water that’s deeper than 1 metre? **No**.

Will it survive for over a half hour or so in about 5cm (2") of water? **Yes**.

What this all means is that an iPhone 8 (that isn’t cracked or otherwise compromised) will survive a water accident that [caused significant damage and function degradation to older iPhone hardware.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205423/does-the-iphone-5s-have-any-built-in-water-protection-mechanisms)

**Steam**

In terms of steam, no, it's not *officially* rated against that criteria (from memory it'd need to have an IP rating of 69 for that).

However, if you're just talking about leaving it on the bathroom bench while you have a shower, then it'll be fine<sup>1</sup> assuming it's not going to be in there for a prolonged period of time and that the steam isn't produced from extremely high heat.

<sup>1. Based on the fact I have two teenage daughters who have used iPods and iPhones like this for years (and they don't even have an IP rating)!</sup>

Comment: My husband took his iPhone 8 in the pool for less than 10 seconds and we now own a useless iPhone. They cannot be submerged no matter what the rating is!

Comment: I took my husbands iPhone 8 Plus to Apple and Verizon and the first thing they said is it can’t get submerged! Won’t ‘test’ it again.

Comment: I would second this - IP67 is for accidental gentle submersion and not something you would test. Additionally, if the device has been dropped before the submersion - even if it was made IP67 in the factory, things may have shifted or gaps opened internally where water could seem in and then corrode later or over time. I’m sure there are many people with devices that are damaged due to water - IP67 rating or not.

Comment: So the answer is actually "yes" - it is waterproof in certain situations. Same as anything that is waterproof. Is your coat waterproof? Yes. Will it keep you dry standing under a waterfall for 10 hours? No. Does my boat float? Yes. Will it float when full of water? No. Are my oven gloves heat proof? Yes. Can I touch the sun with them? No. Is a mug watertight? Yes. But I cracked it and my coffee won't stay in it. Of course an iPhone 8 costs more than most mugs and finding out its no longer ip67 waterproof is a one way street.
My point is the answer "no" is wrong, but the caveats are good.

Comment: iPhones are water-_resistant_, not water-_proof_. They’re designed to withstand accidental splashes, drops of rainwater, etc., but don’t expect them to survive if they sink to the bottom of a pool. Also, note that the water-resistance degrades over time, so a newer iPhone is more likely to withstand water than an older one.